# double quotes escaping in golang exec

Tags: go, escaping, double-quotes

i need to run following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'" output_320x240_boxed.png
```

so i execute:

```
cmd = exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "input.jpg", "-vf", "scale=\"'if(gt(a,4/3),640,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,300)'\"", "output_320x240_boxed.png")
```

it fails with following error:

```
Error when evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,300)"'.
Maybe the expression for out_w:'"if(gt(a,4/3),640,-1)' or for out_h:'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,300)"' is self-referencing.
```

Command works when executed in command line.
Why does it happen and how can i escape those double quotes to prevent this error?

Comment: Use backquotes \` and \` for your Go string literals

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you execute the given `ffmpeg` command line, your shell parses it into a set of command line arguments that are essentially:

```
{
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    "input.jpg",
    "-vf",
    "scale='if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'",
    "output_320x240_boxed.png",
}
```

The extra quotes in the `scale=...` argument interpreted by the shell, rather than being passed on to the underlying program.  So when executing the same program with Go, where you are passing a list of arguments directly, you should leave out those extra quotes.